# How to use ng-repeat with ng-hide (for html select)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I need you help with AngularJS. I have to model this situation: I have two `select`. The first one is used to choose a "main user". The other one is used to choose a "secondary user". When I take a user from the first `select` I must hide that user from the second `select`. This is my (cut) html:

```
<div data-ng-controller="appointmentsController">
     <!-- stuff stuff stuff -->
     <div data-ng-controller="usersController">
         <select id="appointments-users" data-ng-change="changeMainUser()" data-ng-options="userith.ID as userith.lastName for userith in users" data-ng-model="selectedUserID.ID">
              <option value="">Scegli utente principale...</option>
         </select>

         <select id="appointments-secondary-users" multiple data-ng-multiple="true" data-ng-model="secondaryUserIDs.IDs">
             <option data-ng-repeat="userith in users" data-ng-hide="userith.ID === selectedUserID.ID" value="{{userith.ID}}">{{userith.lastName}}</option>
         </select>
     </div>
     <!-- stuff stuff stuff -->
</div>
```

`usersController` is a simple controller that contains a user array called "users". `appointmentsController` contains lots of things among which these two objects:

```
$scope.selectedUserID = {
    ID: $scope.$parent.user.ID
};
$scope.secondaryUserIDs = {
    IDs: null
};
```

Unfortunately, the `data-ng-hide` in the second select seems to be ignored. I need your help to understand why. Thank you in advance.

**EDIT:** thanks to the Maxim Shoustin's suggestions I created a filter for my angular app and I used that filter to show/hide the right secondary users. I did this way:

```
<div data-ng-controller="appointmentsController">
         <!-- stuff stuff stuff -->
         <div data-ng-controller="usersController">
             <select id="appointments-users" data-ng-change="changeMainUser()" data-ng-options="userith.ID as userith.lastName for userith in users" data-ng-model="selectedUserID.ID">
                  <option value="">Scegli utente principale...</option>
             </select>

             <select id="appointments-secondary-users" multiple data-ng-multiple="true" data-ng-model="secondaryUserIDs.IDs">
                 <option data-ng-repeat="userith in users | usersFilter: selectedUserID.ID" value="{{userith.ID}}">{{userith.lastName}}</option>
             </select>
         </div>
         <!-- stuff stuff stuff -->
    </div>
```

This is the filter linked to my angular app:

```
app.filter('usersFilter', function() {
   return function( items, types) {
    var filtered = [];

    angular.forEach(items, function(item) {
        if(item.ID !== types){
            filtered.push(item);
        }
    });

    return filtered;
  };
});
```

Comment: use custom filtering instead: `data-ng-repeat="userith in users | myFilter: selectedUserID.ID`. See example: http://plnkr.co/edit/b0LMJzUiJy0NO9Hk0oWt?p=preview

Comment: Yes, I've thought about it, but I don't know how. I thought that ng-hide was a simple and suitable solution. EDIT: I'll check your example!

Comment: See example I posted.

Comment: Yes, it works! Thank you for leading me to the "angular filtering world".